# Runtime error 1004 on Save (Thisworkbook.save) Works on one machine and not on another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data entry userform and when user saves data to sheet. I want to save the Excel file - to achieve this I use     ThisWorkbook.Save and this works like a charm on my machine.

The file is created and saved as a .XLSM file in Excel 2016 (windows 64 bit).

Now when I distribute the same to my peers at office - some machines work fine.

Some machines throw a runtime 1004 error save method of worksheet class failed.

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim xWs As Worksheet

Dim xName As String
xName = "data"
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If xWs.Name <> xName Then
            xWs.Visible = False
        End If
Next
ThisWorkbook.Save        '<<<< Runtime 1004 Error on this line
Unload Me
Application.Quit
```

On checking the file, the data is saved to the sheet but the error throws up.

What could be the potential reason for this?

Just something that came to my mind based on 
      "https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm" 
Users can open my file (type .xlsm) in any version of excel excel 2007 / excel  2003 ? Is that the root cause? If yes what is my way around?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is how you distribute the file.
My guess is that you email it to them and they open it from the email?
What happens is the file is in a position where you can't save it.

Ask your colleagues to save as the file on the desktop or documents folder where you know for sure they have full read and write capabilities.
Then open the file.

This has bugged me also a few times.
It's easy to forget.

Comment: Yes the user dowloads from gmail in to the downloads folder.  Tried moving the file to desktop and still got the same error - very strange.

THe user has full admin rights (workgroup user no domain or anything) on this computer

Comment: Or better - save [a copy of] the file on a network share, and email a link to the file instead of an attachment. Files opened straight-from-email attachment, modified, and then re-sent, are a PITA - especially when links to external files are involved: expect them to break all the time.

Comment: I copied the file from downloads folder to the desktop. All was well. Did not check on the file attributes (Read only). Will check tomorrow and get back with my outcomes.
 
Thanks to tim-williams / mathieu-guindon for your valuable insights.

Comment: Update:

IT did windows update and did some cleanup. and the file with no changes to the code started working without any errors. 

I am not sure what the issue was but it is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`. Create a variable to store your workbook(s) and use that variable. Your problem is probably due to the fact that your `ActiveWorkbook`is pointing to a different workbook than the one you wanted.

Comment: activeworkbooks code is for hiding the sheets. that part works without any runtime error

The problem is with the thisworkbook.save

Also there are palces in my module where their is no activeworkbook refrence.

sample from another procedure 

Cells(rowselect, 2) = Me.txtdate.Value
Cells(rowselect, 3) = Me.txtname.Value
Cells(rowselect, 20) = Now()
ThisWorkbook.Save

this also throws an error << RUNTIME >>

Comment: @ShanmugamArumugam but he does have a point. If the code runs when another workbook is active then the code will error out. Always use ThisWorkbook.

Comment: Done. I changed the code in my routine to thisworkbook from activeworkbook.

But why does the runtime error occur on another procedure with no activebook. reference

Comment: Thanks to aiyuni and Andreas for your valuable insights.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not saying the activeworkbook is related to the error. But it can cause another error